# How to move color value from colors object to data object based on colorId

Tags: javascript

I have one quick question, how I can move the color value color: 'red' from the colors object to the data object? I have tried a different way and am still on the problem side.

```
const colors = [
    { id: 1, color: "red" },
    { id: 2, color: "blue" },
    { id: 3, color: "green" }
];
const data = [
    {
        colorId: 1
    },
    {
        colorId: 2
    },
    {
        colorId: 3
    }
];
```

Here is the solution that showed me undefined

```
const checkresult = data.forEach(a=>{
    colors.forEach(b =>{
        if(a.colorId=== b.id){
            return Object.assign(a.colorId, b.color)
        }
    })
})
console.log(checkresult)
```

But I want this solution

```
data = [
    {
        colorId: 1,
        color: 'red'
    }
    {
        colorId: 2,
        color: 'blue'
    }
    {
        colorId: 3,
        color: 'green'
    }
];
```

Comment: Your return does nothing inside the forEach, you need to use map instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can :

- loop through data with `array.foreach`
- and use `array.find` to find first iteration of matching color

```js
const colors = [
        { id: 1, color: "red" },
        { id: 2, color: "blue" },
        { id: 3, color: "green" }
    ];
    const data = [
        {
            colorId: 1
        },
        {
            colorId: 2
        },
        {
            colorId: 3
        }
    ];

    data.forEach(color => color['color'] = colors.find(col => col.id === color.colorId).color);

    console.log(data);
```

Comment: Thanks, my dear. I got the perfect solution that I was looking for.

Comment: great i it help you ;) may i help you to mark the reply if it solve your issue to close the topic ?

Comment: I am not sure how I can close the topic except delete the question.

Comment: you have a little tick to close topic at left of reply near reply score